# Set multiple dictionary values from input values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to set multiple dictionary values in python from input values but always returns error notification. but if I declare the dictionary in script it will running well. So I tried:

```
adj=defaultdict(list)

iteration=input("the number of edges that constructed: ")
for i in range (0,int(iteration)):
    #A(vertices1)  B(vertices2) W(weight)
    abw=input("A B W : ")
    if len(abw)==1:
        a=int(abw)
        valueBW=(None)
        if a in adj:
            adj[a].append(())
        else:
            adj[a].append(())
            #dict.fromkeys(a,None)
    else:
        a,b,w=abw.split(' ')
        a=int(a)
        valueBW=(int(b),int(w))
        if a in adj:
            adj[a].append(valueBW)
        else:
            #adj.update({a : [(int(b),int(w))]})
            adj[a].append(valueBW)
```

this is the input example :

```
the number of edges that constructed: 8
A B W : 0 1 4
A B W : 0 3 8
A B W : 1 4 1
A B W : 1 2 2
A B W : 4 2 3
A B W : 2 5 3
A B W : 3 4 2
A B W : 5
```

this is the dictionary if I declare it in the code :

```
adj = {
  0: [(1, 4),(3, 8)],
  1: [(4, 1),(2, 2)],
  4: [(2, 3)],
  2: [(5, 3)],
  3: [(4, 2)],
  5: [],
  }
```

Was my code right?

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: If you get an error, post the *entire* traceback.

Comment: ok thanks. fortunately my problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you wanted, but I *believe* that this is what you're after:

```
# Always show your imports - we don't know if
# you got defaultdict from here or somewhere else
from collections import defaultdict

adj=defaultdict(list)

iteration=input("the number of edges that constructed: ")

# You can omit the start if it's zero.
# and if you're not using the variable,
# indicate that by using `_` as your name
for _ in range (int(iteration)):
    #A(vertices1)  B(vertices2) W(weight)
    abw=input("A B W : ")
    if len(abw)==1:
        a=int(abw)
        # Don't append anything
        # just access it so that
        # it exists.
        adj[a]
    else:
        # By default, `.split()` uses any whitespace.
        # This makes `1     2 3` work just fine.
        a,b,w=abw.split()
        a=int(a)
        valueBW=(int(b),int(w))
        adj[a].append(valueBW)
```

Using your provided input, this gives me:

```
{0: [(1, 4), (3, 8)],
 1: [(4, 1), (2, 2)],
 2: [(5, 3)],
 3: [(4, 2)],
 4: [(2, 3)],
 5: []}
```

Which looks like your expected output. Do note that dictionaries aren't ordered, so to get it to display like this I used:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(adj)
```

Comment: thanks for your kindness. now my problem has been solved

Comment: @HanifKh If this solves your problem the best method of thanks is to mark the answer accepted by clicking the checkmark `<----` to the left. If it was *really* helpful, you can upvote, too.